# Probability that a straight line through a polygon can cut it into 2 parts of different colors

Tags: probability, combinatorics, geometry

Suppose I have an $n$-sided perfect polygon with $n$ corners. Let $r$ of the corners be 'red', and $n-r$ corners be 'blue'. That way, every corner is either red or blue. If we randomly assign the colors to the corners, what is the probability, based on $n$ and $r$, that I can draw a straight line that cuts the polygon into 2 parts? Where one side only has blue corners, and one with only red?

For example, in the image below. $n=5$, and $r=2$. WLOG, we can pin the first red corner onto the top of the shape. Here we can see that we can draw a straight line in $\frac{2}{4}$ or $\frac{1}{2}$ of the possible combinations.

[image]

My question is, can we find a formula that gives us the probability $P$ of cutting the shape based on a $n$ and $r$?

If it helps, I have been able to show that the total number of possible lines for any $n$-sided perfect polygon is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ ($+1$ if you include the possibility of drawing no lines)

Comment: You also need to consider the probability of same colors going to adjacent vertices when you randomly assign colors to the vertices. _Visibly_ there are $n$ such arrangements.

Comment: Are corners and colors considered identical or not? I mean, when you rotate and get same figure, are they identical or not (for corners), as well as when swap two reds, are these 2 possible configuration identical or not (for colors)?

Comment: @Snowball I would prefer that both colors and corners are identical, but I don't think it matters in the probability

Comment: @ComplexEeno ah, actually you are right, both seems to give same answer. Think of the problem as straight line with $n+r$ points on it (last r points are first r points). Then cutting into 2 parts of is same as $r$ red's being consecutive. We have $n$ such case among all possible colorings. And all possible colorings is just ${n \choose r}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the red vertices to be adjacent to be able to draw a separating line.

Of the ${n \choose r}$ ways of positioning the $n$ vertices, $1$ has the red vertices as the first $r$, and so by rotational symmetry $n$ have the red vertices adjacent.

This gives a probability of $\dfrac{n}{n \choose r}$, at least when $0 < r < n$.  In your example, this is $\frac{5}{10}=\frac12$.

If $r=0$ or $r=n$ then you do not need a separating line, so this does not apply in those cases.